# TestNG initial setup

Tags: testing

I’m trying to configure TestNG on my local machine. I followed the instructions in this tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_environment.htm .  When I try to invoke the testing.xml I get the following error:

[image]

Can anyone direct me on any missing steps in this tutorial ?